# PIC18F2550 assembly code for turning led on with a switch isn't working

Tags: assembly, pic, microchip, mplab, xc8

This is the code made in MPLAB X with compiler XC8 :

```
 PROCESSOR 18F2550

#include <xc.h>

    ; CONFIG1L
  CONFIG  PLLDIV = 1            ; PLL Prescaler Selection bits (No prescale (4 MHz oscillator input drives PLL directly))
  CONFIG  CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2    ; System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /1][96 MHz PLL Src: /2])
  CONFIG  USBDIV = 1            ; USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes directly from the primary oscillator block with no postscale)

; CONFIG1H
  CONFIG  FOSC = HS             ; Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator (HS))
  CONFIG  FCMEN = OFF           ; Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
  CONFIG  IESO = OFF            ; Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

; CONFIG2L
  CONFIG  PWRT = OFF            ; Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
  CONFIG  BOR = OFF             ; Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware and software)
  CONFIG  BORV = 3              ; Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
  CONFIG  VREGEN = OFF          ; USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

; CONFIG2H
  CONFIG  WDT = OFF             ; Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
  CONFIG  WDTPS = 32768         ; Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

; CONFIG3H
  CONFIG  CCP2MX = OFF          ; CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RB3)
  CONFIG  PBADEN = OFF          ; PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as digital I/O on Reset)
  CONFIG  LPT1OSC = OFF         ; Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
  CONFIG  MCLRE = OFF           ; MCLR Pin Enable bit (RE3 input pin enabled; MCLR pin disabled)

; CONFIG4L
  CONFIG  STVREN = OFF          ; Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will not cause Reset)
  CONFIG  LVP = OFF             ; Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP disabled)
  CONFIG  XINST = OFF           ; Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

; CONFIG5L
  CONFIG  CP0 = OFF             ; Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
  CONFIG  CP1 = OFF             ; Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
  CONFIG  CP2 = OFF             ; Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
  CONFIG  CP3 = OFF             ; Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)

; CONFIG5H
  CONFIG  CPB = OFF             ; Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
  CONFIG  CPD = OFF             ; Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

; CONFIG6L
  CONFIG  WRT0 = OFF            ; Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
  CONFIG  WRT1 = OFF            ; Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
  CONFIG  WRT2 = OFF            ; Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
  CONFIG  WRT3 = OFF            ; Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)

; CONFIG6H
  CONFIG  WRTC = OFF            ; Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
  CONFIG  WRTB = OFF            ; Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
  CONFIG  WRTD = OFF            ; Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

; CONFIG7L
  CONFIG  EBTR0 = OFF           ; Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
  CONFIG  EBTR1 = OFF           ; Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
  CONFIG  EBTR2 = OFF           ; Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
  CONFIG  EBTR3 = OFF           ; Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

; CONFIG7H
  CONFIG  EBTRB = OFF           ; Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// config statements shou


#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

PSECT resetVect, class=CODE, delta=2
resetVect:
    PAGESEL main

    goto main

PSECT code, delta=2
main:
    SETF 0f93h ;0f93h is TRISB
    BCF 0f93h, 2
    BSF 0f93h, 1 

    loop:

    BTFSS 0f81h, 1 ;0f81h is PORTB
    goto SET_RB2:

    BCF 0f81h, 2

    goto loop

    SET_RB2:
    BSF 0f81h, 2

    goto loop    

    goto main

END resetVect
```

The corresponding Proteus simulation is this:

[image]

When I press the button, RB1 is ground, and when it's ground then RB2 should be set to high and make the led open, but that isn't working. Notice, the code in C is working fine :

```
   // CONFIG1L
#pragma config PLLDIV = 1       // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (No prescale (4 MHz oscillator input drives PLL directly))
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2// System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /1][96 MHz PLL Src: /2])
#pragma config USBDIV = 1       // USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes directly from the primary oscillator block with no postscale)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator (HS))
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOR = OFF        // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware and software)
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
#pragma config VREGEN = OFF     // USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = OFF     // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RB3)
#pragma config PBADEN = OFF     // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as digital I/O on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Enable bit (RE3 input pin enabled; MCLR pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = OFF     // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will not cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>



#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000


void main(void) {
    TRISB = 0xFF;
    TRISB &= ~(1 << 2);
    TRISB |= 1 << 1;
            
    while(1) {
        if(PORTB & (1<<1)){
            PORTB &= ~(1 << 2);
        } 
        else {
            PORTB |= 1 << 2;

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using raw addresses rather than the defined register names?  That makes your assembly code completely incomprehensible.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm just reading from the datasheet, I could only find the mem addresses, when I put the label like PORTB, it gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

I do not know anything about the Proteus tools. How does the simulation work without a crystal connected to the oscillator pins?

This is how I would write your application for the Microchip pic-as tool chain:

```
; File:     main.S
; Target:   PIC18F2550
; Author:   dan1138
; Date:     2023-DEC-07
; Compiler: pic-as(v2.45)
; IDE:      MPLABX v6.15
;
; Description:
;
;
; Add to the MPLABX project Additional options:
;   -Wa,-a -Wl,-presetVec=0h,-phi_int_vec=08h,-plo_int_vec=18h
;
;                             PIC18F2550
;                    +------------:_:------------+
;          VPP ->  1 : RE3/MCLRn/VPP     PGD/RB7 : 28 <> PGD
;              ->  2 : RA0/AN0           PGC/RB6 : 27 <> PGC
;              <>  3 : RA1/AN1           PGM/RB5 : 26 <> 
;              <>  4 : RA2/AN2          AN11/RB4 : 25 <> 
;              <>  5 : RA3/AN3           AN9/RB3 : 24 <> 
;              <>  6 : RA4/C1OUT         AN8/RB2 : 23 <> 
;              <>  7 : RA5/AN4          AN10/RB1 : 22 <> 
;          GND <>  8 : VSS              AN12/RB0 : 21 <> 
;        20MHz <>  9 : RA7/OSC1              VDD : 20 <- 5v0
;        20MHz <> 10 : RA6/OSC2              VSS : 19 <- GND
;    32.768KHz <> 11 : RC0/SOSCO       RX/DT/RC7 : 18 <> 
;    32.768KHz <> 12 : RC1/SOSCI       TX/CK/RC6 : 17 <> 
;              <> 13 : RC2/CCP1           D+/RC5 : 16 <- 
;              <> 14 : VUSB               D-/RC4 : 15 <- 
;                    +---------------------------:
;                               DIP-28
;  Note: 
;   RC4,RC5 can only be used as digital inputs when the USB transceiver is not used.
;
    processor   18F2550
    pagewidth   132 
    radix       dec
; PIC18F2550 Configuration Bit Settings

; Assembly source line config statements

; CONFIG1L
  CONFIG  PLLDIV = 5            ; PLL Prescaler Selection bits (Divide by 5 (20 MHz oscillator input))
  CONFIG  CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2    ; System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /1][96 MHz PLL Src: /2])
  CONFIG  USBDIV = 2            ; USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes from the 96 MHz PLL divided by 2)

; CONFIG1H
  CONFIG  FOSC = HSPLL_HS       ; Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator, PLL enabled (HSPLL))
  CONFIG  FCMEN = OFF           ; Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
  CONFIG  IESO = OFF            ; Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

; CONFIG2L
  CONFIG  PWRT = OFF            ; Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
  CONFIG  BOR = OFF             ; Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware and software)
  CONFIG  BORV = 3              ; Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
  CONFIG  VREGEN = OFF          ; USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

; CONFIG2H
  CONFIG  WDT = OFF             ; Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
  CONFIG  WDTPS = 32768         ; Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

; CONFIG3H
  CONFIG  CCP2MX = ON           ; CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
  CONFIG  PBADEN = OFF          ; PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as digital I/O on Reset)
  CONFIG  LPT1OSC = OFF         ; Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
  CONFIG  MCLRE = ON            ; MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)

; CONFIG4L
  CONFIG  STVREN = ON           ; Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
  CONFIG  LVP = OFF             ; Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP disabled)
  CONFIG  XINST = OFF           ; Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

; CONFIG5L
  CONFIG  CP0 = OFF             ; Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
  CONFIG  CP1 = OFF             ; Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
  CONFIG  CP2 = OFF             ; Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
  CONFIG  CP3 = OFF             ; Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)

; CONFIG5H
  CONFIG  CPB = OFF             ; Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
  CONFIG  CPD = OFF             ; Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

; CONFIG6L
  CONFIG  WRT0 = OFF            ; Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
  CONFIG  WRT1 = OFF            ; Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
  CONFIG  WRT2 = OFF            ; Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
  CONFIG  WRT3 = OFF            ; Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)

; CONFIG6H
  CONFIG  WRTC = OFF            ; Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
  CONFIG  WRTB = OFF            ; Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
  CONFIG  WRTD = OFF            ; Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

; CONFIG7L
  CONFIG  EBTR0 = OFF           ; Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
  CONFIG  EBTR1 = OFF           ; Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
  CONFIG  EBTR2 = OFF           ; Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
  CONFIG  EBTR3 = OFF           ; Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

; CONFIG7H
  CONFIG  EBTRB = OFF           ; Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
;
;   Specify the System clock frequency in Hz that this code must setuop
;
#define FSYS 48000000
;   
;   Specify the Peripheral clock frequency in Hz
;
#define FCY  (FSYS/4)
;
; Include device specific definitions for Special Function Registers
;
#include <xc.inc>
;
; Preprocessor macro to help with LFSR opcode
;
#define FSR(x) (x)
;
    psect   resetVec,reloc=2,class=CODE,delta=1
;
resetVec:
    clrf    TBLPTRU,c
    goto    Start
;
    psect   hi_int_vec,reloc=2,class=CODE,delta=1
;
    goto    HighIsrHandler
;
    psect   LowIsr_data,class=COMRAM,space=1,delta=1,lowdata,noexec
;
    global  WREG_save,STATUS_save,BSR_save
;
WREG_save:      ds  1
STATUS_save:    ds  1
BSR_save:       ds  1
;
    psect   lo_int_vec,reloc=2,class=CODE,delta=1
;
LowIsrVec:
    movff   WREG,WREG_save
    movff   STATUS,STATUS_save
    movff   BSR,BSR_save
;
LowIsrHandler:
;
    movff   BSR_save,BSR
    movff   STATUS_save,STATUS
    movff   WREG_save,WREG
    retfie  0
;
    psect   HighIsr_code,reloc=2,class=CODE,delta=1
;
HighIsrHandler:
    retfie  1
;
    psect   start_code,reloc=2,class=CODE,delta=1
;
Start:
    bcf     INTCON,INTCON_GIEH_POSITION,0 ; Disable all interrupts
    bcf     INTCON,INTCON_GIEL_POSITION,0
    bsf     RCON,RCON_IPEN_POSITION,0 ; Enable interrupt priority
;
    movlw   0x00                ; Set primary oscillator as system clock source
    movwf   OSCCON,c            ;
;
    movlw   0x0F                ; Setup all GPIO pins
    movwf   ADCON1,c            ; for digital I/O
;
    goto    main
;
;
    psect   main_code,reloc=2,class=CODE,delta=1
;
main:
    setf    TRISB,c
    bcf     TRISB,TRISB_TRISB2_POSITION,c
    bsf     TRISB,TRISB_TRISB1_POSITION,c

;
AppLoop:
    btfss   PORTB,PORTB_RB1_POSITION,c
    bra     SET_RB2
    bcf     LATB,LATB_LATB2_POSITION,c
    bra     AppLoop
SET_RB2:
    bsf     LATB,LATB_LATB2_POSITION,c
    goto    AppLoop
;
    END     resetVec
```

Comment: although this code solved one warning I had, it still didn't work in the simulation, and also again, the c code works just fine in the simulation

Comment: there's an oscillator  Proteus uses that's assumed, so I don't have to add it manually, also the power source is assumed.

Comment: @JohnSall, I have tested this code with the MPLABX v6.15 simulator. It does what I expect. You will need to explain why you do not see it working with Proteus.